# How are ints allowed to be assigned to a Java wrapper class

Tags: java, int, wrapper, primitive-types

How is this following code legal and what does this do exactly?

```
int i = new Integer(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Java Language Specification,

[§5.2 Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

Your code demonstrates an unboxing conversion from `Integer` to `int`. *The language spec says it is allowed, so it is, otherwise you are not using Java.*

For more info on what an unboxing conversion is, visit [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). To summarise, it's basically converting from a reference type to its primitive counterpart. In this case, `Integer` is the reference type and `int` is the primitive type.